# What is the fastest way to generate a .d.ts file for a browser version of a library?

Tags: typescript, module, typescript-typings, rollup, umd

I have a quite large library written in Typescript 2.3.4 that is exporting a lot of ES6 modules and classes. I now need to use the library in an older browser app, written in typescript but using internal modules only. I managed to build a browser version of the library (thus polluting the global namespace) using rollup, and it works fine, at run time !

My problem now is to generate the typings (.d.ts) for the library when used as a global.

My code is compiled starting from a single index.ts file containing something like this:

```
import * as Promises from "./Promises";
export { Promises };

import * as CommonInterfaces from "./CommonInterfaces";
export { CommonInterfaces };

import * as Utils from "./Utils";
export { Utils };

import * as DomainEvents from "./DomainEvents";
export { DomainEvents };
...
```

I build the library in es6 modules and then use rollup to obtain a monolithic umd file that when loaded in a browser environment creates a single property called DDDTools in the "window" global, containing all of the modules exported, like this

```
window.DDDTools
            +-- Promises
            +-- CommonInterfaces
            +-- Utils
            +-- DomainEvents
            +-- ...
```

this is exactly what I would obtain if I developed the library using internal modules (namespaces) instead of external modules.

Since the library is developed using external modules I can't use the d.ts files generated by the tsc compiler which are containing something like this (for the Utils module):

```
file: Utils/index.d.ts

export { ObjectIterator } from "./ObjectIterator";
export { SimpleGuid } from "./SimpleGuid";
export { SimpleIdentityMap } from "./SimpleIdentityMap";
```

taking the object iterator as an example

```
file: Utils/ObjectIterator.d.ts

export interface IObjectIteratorItem {
    value: any;
    propertyNameOrIndex: string;
    parentObject: any;
}
export declare class ObjectIterator {
    private srcObject;
    private knownObjects;
    private toBeTraversed;
    private traversed;
    private currentStackItem;
    constructor(srcObject: any);
    hasNext(): boolean;
    getCurrent(): IObjectIteratorItem;
    moveNext(): void;
    reset(): void;
    private isKnownObject(obj);
    private addToKnownObjects(obj);
    private addToStack(obj);
}
```

these .d.ts are fine if I use the library in my typescript sources as external modules, so I can write

```
/* fine, but make*/
import { ObjectIterator } from "DDDTools/Utils";  

let oi = new ObjectIterator( ... // <-- and here my editor would show all the intellisense that makes typescript really cool ;)
```

BUT how do I say to typescript that exists a global whose name is DDDTools and that contains all the modules it exports ?

My first try was:

```
import * as dddtools from "DDDTools";
declare var DDDTools: dddtools;
```

but this makes my file an external module, and my poor browser app (containing a lot of files) is still namespace based (internal modules), doesn't compile anymore.

I think I need a way to create a .d.ts containing something like this

```
declare namespace DDDTools.Utils {
    export interface IObjectIteratorItem {
        value: any;
        propertyNameOrIndex: string;
        parentObject: any;
    }
    export declare class ObjectIterator {
        private srcObject;
        private knownObjects;
        private toBeTraversed;
        private traversed;
        private currentStackItem;
        constructor(srcObject: any);
        hasNext(): boolean;
        getCurrent(): IObjectIteratorItem;
        moveNext(): void;
        reset(): void;
        private isKnownObject(obj);
        private addToKnownObjects(obj);
        private addToStack(obj);
    }
}
```

Am I right ? If yes is out there a way to make it "automatically" ? I tried using tsc with the module option set to "system" (or amd) and outputting everything to a single file with the outFile option, but got something like this:

```
declare module "DDDTools/Utils/ObjectIterator" {
    export interface IObjectIteratorItem {
        value: any;
        propertyNameOrIndex: string;
        parentObject: any;
    }
    export class ObjectIterator {
        private srcObject;
        private knownObjects;
        private toBeTraversed;
        private traversed;
        private currentStackItem;
        constructor(srcObject: any);
        hasNext(): boolean;
        getCurrent(): IObjectIteratorItem;
        moveNext(): void;
        reset(): void;
        private isKnownObject(obj);
        private addToKnownObjects(obj);
        private addToStack(obj);
    }
}
... and so forth for each ES6 module I created
```

which is really really near to what I need, if only that `declare module "DDDTools/Utils/ObjectIterator"` could become a `declare namespace DDDTools.Utils.ObjectIterator` ... but you know it isn't

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the fastest way to generate a .d.ts file for a browser version of a library?

The fastest way is to just embrace the NPM ecosystem and let something like webpack do the bundling.

## More

outFile is just pain that everyone can live without https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html so you will not find tooling that solves a broken code base. Better to fix the codebase instead of writing tooling to pile on to an unmaintainable system.

Comment: Of course you're right (as always ;-) ) ! Mine was just an attempt to save some time... you know my code base has grown to more than 100 files, and involves a code generator, which is still producing namespaces . When I first started this project, I moved to typescript from .net, and the concept of namespace was much more familiar than the external modules, but of course they are the path to maintainability... I've already started the conversion, and no monolithic .d.ts at all. Thanks